# Hide some columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have code working as below.

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import yfinance as yf
import talib as ta
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('portfoy.csv')

def anlik_fiyat(data):
  return si.get_live_price(data)

hisseler=df["hisse"]
liste=[]

for hisse in hisseler:
    fiyat = round(anlik_fiyat(hisse),2)
    print(hisse," geldi")
    liste.append(fiyat)
    
df.insert(5, 'guncel', liste)

#Hesaplamalar yap
m = df['satis_fiyati'].isna()
acik=(df.loc[m, 'alis_fiyati']*df.loc[m, 'miktar']).sum()

print("\n", "-"*32, "AÇIK POZİSYONLAR", "-"*32, "\n")    
print(df.loc[df['satis_fiyati'].isna()])      
print("Açık Pozisyonlar:", acik)
```

When it works, the results are as follows.

```
     tip     hisse alis_tarihi  alis_fiyati  miktar  guncel  satis_fiyati satis_tarihi
1  hisse  ISCTR.IS  27-06-2022         4.56      21    4.93           NaN          NaN
2  hisse  SAHOL.IS  04-07-2022        19.21       5   19.73           NaN          NaN
5  hisse  SAHOL.IS  07-07-2022        18.50       5   19.73           NaN          NaN
6  hisse  AYGAZ.IS  21-07-2022        35.20       3   35.50           NaN          NaN
7  hisse  KCHOL.IS  21-07-2022        36.12       3   36.00           NaN          NaN
Açık Pozisyonlar: 498.27
```

I don't want to see `tip`, `satis_fiyati` and `satis_tarihi` columns among the results.

Ps: If I add the following lines

```
df.drop(['tip'], inplace=True, axis=1)
df.drop(['satis_fiyati'], inplace=True, axis=1)
df.drop(['satis_tarihi'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Gives an error. Also, this is a very long method.
How can I solve this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this small example will help you

---

Lets say, we have dataframe like this and our goal is to exclude (or include) some columns from the results

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[7,9,5], 'c' : [9, 6, 4], 'd':[0, 0, 0]})
    a   b   c   d
0   1   7   9   0
1   2   9   6   0
2   3   5   4   0
```

List of columns we want to include/exclude:

```
col = ['a', 'c']
```

To **include** columns:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(col)]
# or df.loc[:, col]
# or df[col]

a   c
0   1   9
1   2   6
2   3   4
```

To **exclude** columns:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(col)]

b   d
0   7   0
1   9   0
2   5   0
```